# Default crontab that executes cron.(hourly|daily|weekly|monthly)

Tags: cron

I have to build a crontab that will execute (with `run-parts`) any script located in the standard /etc/cron.(hourly|daily|weekly|monthly) folders.

I have never done this before.

Does this look correct?

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
0 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
0 0 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
0 0 * * 1 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
0 0 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: That looks good

Comment: Looks good, although it may be better to use a program like `anacron` for the weekly and monthly runs.  This will make sure the jobs will be run, even if the computer happens to be off during the time your scheduled.  Some cron-daemons have a similar functionality built-in, but it often uses a special syntax - if your `crond` does, use the special syntax instead for weekly and monthly runs.

Comment: I am using ```cronie```. I am also using Yocto, and their doesn't appear to be any recipes for it ```anacron```

Comment: Maybe do like Debian does and stagger the times a bit, so you don't end up running all those jobs at the same time on a Monday morning.